How to download a subset of dataset from AWS CLI? Either bash script or python solution will be really appreciated
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line
do
  aws s3 cp --no-sign-request s3://.../$line E:/Papua_New_Guinea/ --region us-east-1 --no-sign-request
done <E:/Papua_New_Guinea/filenames.txt


My need is to download a subset of dataset based on a list of file names saved in a txt file. Above is my code. When I directly executed the code in one line in Git Bash prompt, it returned nothing. But when I saved it as .sh script then call bash command to execute the script, it always threw such error message: "fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key " does not exist..."

Each file names in the txt file was listed in a way like this 132122233.tif, which "132122233" is the file id and ".tif" is the file format. Which part of my code went wrong? Could anyone offer some helps?
